# Declare current module as having a particular interface

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a project with a folder in it, each with a module that should have a particular interface:

```
project/
  modules/
    A/index.ts
    B/index.ts
    C/index.ts
```

each of the index.ts files, should adhere to a certain interface.
Something like this:

```
export const foo = ...
export const bar = ...
```

how can I declare that each index.ts file must export a certain interface? *In other words, I need to tell TypeScript that `module.exports` for each of these index.ts files must adhere to a certain interface.*

I filed an issue for this with TypeScript / DefinitelyTyped on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19554

Comment: perhaps I should use module or namespace? Been avoiding that until now perhaps...

Comment: *build them a prison !*

Comment: yes but how lol thanks :)

Comment: `export module x implements y` is not something that's valid, nor is `export namespace x implements y`

Comment: I also tried `export {} as MyInterface`, that syntax is no good either

Comment: Does anyone else like this question besides me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, specifying types that modules must implement is not yet supported, but you can use a convention such as you suggested in the GitHub issue that you linked from.

Well, it actually does work with export forms but you are using invalid export syntax (`export {} as MyInterface`) irrespective of the presence of types.

One way to write this would be

```
export interface MyInterface {
    id: number;
    name:string
}

const m: MyInterface = {
    id: 1
}

export = m;
```

We might think to write it more concisely as

```
export = {id: 1} as MyInterface;
```

which is valid syntax but acts as a type assertion, not an implementation requirement, such that

```
export = {} as MyInterface;
```

typechecks as well. This makes the first form preferable.

Comment: Thanks, I will try something that you suggested, seems like it will suffice for now...does the last thing you mention `export = {} as MyInterface;` work? I try to avoid overwriting `module.exports` if I can avoid it though.

Comment: I think using `export default {} as MyInterface` would be preferable, no? and then attach everything to default. Or some other property like default.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer strongly prefer `default`, however you wanted to _type_ the module object itself and that is the closest you can get since `default` is just a named export with syntactic sugar for importing it. It will work with default. However, the `as type` does not work because it is a type assertion and not a type annotation. This allows for example missing properties.